# Aframe based kalidokit 3d body tracking is not working (face tracking works)

Tags: three.js, aframe, mediapipe

I am trying make kalidokit face and body tracking work but no matter what I did I cannot get the body tracking working. Face tracking works perfectly fine. In similar projects such as kalidokit-react face+body tracking works fine, but I guess since I am trying to make it work through a-frame there is a rendering issue I still can't figure out.
Here is my code:

```
*AFRAME.registerComponent("m-avatar", {
   schema: {
      src: { type: "string" },
      motion: { type: "string" },
   },
   async init() {
      this.camera = AFRAME.scenes[0].camera;
      this.scene = this.el.object3D;
      this.renderer = AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer;
      var currentVrm = null;
      var currentMixer = null;
      this.modelSrc = this.data.src; //localavatar;
      this.defaultPose = idlePose;
      this.currentClip = null;
      this.vrm = null;
      this.mixer = null;
   },
   async update(oldData) {
      this.camera = AFRAME.scenes[0].camera;
      this.scene = this.el.object3D;
      this.renderer = AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer;
      var currentVrm = null;
      var currentMixer = null;
      var currentClip = null;
      var currentScene = null;
      var currentCamera = null;
      if (this.data.src !== oldData.src) {
         const _vrmData = await loadVRM(this.modelSrc).then(async (vrm) => {
            currentVrm = vrm;
            this.scene.add(currentVrm.scene);
            const head = currentVrm.humanoid.getBoneNode("head");
            this.camera.position.set(0.0, head.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()).y, 6.0);
            currentMixer = new THREE.AnimationMixer(currentVrm.scene);
            currentMixer.timeScale = 1;
            return await loadMixamoAnimation(this.defaultPose, currentVrm).then(async (clip) => {
               currentClip = currentMixer.clipAction(clip); //.setEffectiveWeight(1.0) doesnwork
               //currentClip.play();
               return [currentVrm, currentMixer, currentClip];
            });
         });
         this.vrm = _vrmData[0];

         this.mixer = _vrmData[1];
         this.currentClip = _vrmData[2];

         const clock = new THREE.Clock();
         clock.start();

         function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            const delta = clock.getDelta();
            if (currentMixer) {
               currentMixer.update(delta);
            }
            if (currentVrm) {
               currentVrm.update(delta);
            }
         }
         animate();
      }

      if (oldData.motion && this.data.motion !== oldData.motion && this.vrm && this.mixer) {
         if (!this.data.motion.includes("fbx")) {
            // Animate Rotation Helper function
            const rigRotation = (name, rotation = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, dampener = 1, lerpAmount = 0.3) => {
               if (!this.vrm) {
                  return;
               }
               //const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getBoneNode(VRMSchema.HumanoidBoneName[name]); //
               const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getRawBoneNode(VRMHumanBoneName[name]);

               if (!Part) {
                  return;
               }

               let euler = new THREE.Euler(rotation.x * dampener, rotation.y * dampener, rotation.z * dampener, rotation.rotationOrder || "XYZ");
               let quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(euler);
               Part.quaternion.slerp(quaternion, lerpAmount); // interpolate
            };

            // Animate Position Helper Function
            const rigPosition = (name, position = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, dampener = 1, lerpAmount = 0.3) => {
               if (!this.vrm) {
                  return;
               }
               //const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getBoneNode(VRMSchema.HumanoidBoneName[name]); //
               const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getRawBoneNode(VRMHumanBoneName[name]);

               if (!Part) {
                  return;
               }
               let vector = new THREE.Vector3(position.x * dampener, position.y * dampener, position.z * dampener);
               Part.position.lerp(vector, lerpAmount); // interpolate
            };

            const rigFace = (riggedFace) => {
               if (!this.vrm) {
                  return;
               }
               //rigRotation("Neck", riggedFace.head, 0.7);

               // Blendshapes and Preset Name Schema
               const Blendshape = this.vrm.expressionManager;
               const PresetName = VRMExpressionPresetName;

               // Simple example without winking. Interpolate based on old blendshape, then stabilize blink with `Kalidokit` helper function.
               // for VRM, 1 is closed, 0 is open.
               riggedFace.eye.l = lerp(clamp(1 - riggedFace.eye.l, 0, 1), Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Blink), 0.5);
               riggedFace.eye.r = lerp(clamp(1 - riggedFace.eye.r, 0, 1), Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Blink), 0.5);
               riggedFace.eye = Face.stabilizeBlink(riggedFace.eye, riggedFace.head.y);
               Blendshape.setValue(PresetName.Blink, riggedFace.eye.l);

               // Interpolate and set mouth blendshapes
               Blendshape.setValue(PresetName.Ih, lerp(riggedFace.mouth.shape.I, Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Ih), 0.5));
               Blendshape.setValue(PresetName.Aa, lerp(riggedFace.mouth.shape.A, Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Aa), 0.5));
               Blendshape.setValue(PresetName.Ee, lerp(riggedFace.mouth.shape.E, Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Ee), 0.5));
               Blendshape.setValue(PresetName.Oh, lerp(riggedFace.mouth.shape.O, Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Oh), 0.5));
               Blendshape.setValue(PresetName.Uu, lerp(riggedFace.mouth.shape.U, Blendshape.getValue(PresetName.Uu), 0.5));

               //PUPILS
               //interpolate pupil and keep a copy of the value
               let lookTarget = new THREE.Euler(lerp(oldLookTarget.x, riggedFace.pupil.y, 0.4), lerp(oldLookTarget.y, riggedFace.pupil.x, 0.4), 0, "XYZ");
               oldLookTarget.copy(lookTarget); 

               const yaw = THREE.MathUtils.RAD2DEG * lookTarget.y;
               const pitch = THREE.MathUtils.RAD2DEG * lookTarget.x;
               this.vrm.lookAt.applier.applyYawPitch(yaw, pitch);
            };

            const clock = new THREE.Clock();
            //clock.start();
            currentVrm = this.vrm;
            currentMixer = this.mixer;

            if (currentVrm && currentMixer) {
               /* VRM Character Animator */
               const animateVRM = async (results) => {
                  // Take the results from `Holistic` and animate character based on its Face, Pose, and Hand Keypoints.
                  let riggedPose, riggedLeftHand, riggedRightHand, riggedFace;

                  const faceLandmarks = results.faceLandmarks;
                  // Pose 3D Landmarks are with respect to Hip distance in meters
                  const pose3DLandmarks = results.za; //results.ea;
                  // Pose 2D landmarks are with respect to videoWidth and videoHeight
                  const pose2DLandmarks = results.poseLandmarks;
                  // Be careful, hand landmarks may be reversed
                  const leftHandLandmarks = results.rightHandLandmarks;
                  const rightHandLandmarks = results.leftHandLandmarks;

                  const videoElement = document.getElementById("video-in");

                  // Animate Face
                  if (faceLandmarks) {
                     riggedFace = await Face.solve(faceLandmarks, {
                        runtime: "tfjs", //mediapipe doesnt work makes the eyes close
                        video: videoElement,
                     });
                     rigFace(riggedFace);
                  }

                  // Animate Pose
                  if (pose2DLandmarks && pose3DLandmarks) {
                     riggedPose = await Pose.solve(pose3DLandmarks, pose2DLandmarks, {
                        runtime: "mediapipe",
                        video: videoElement,
                     }); 

                     rigRotation("Hips", riggedPose.Hips.rotation, 0.7);

                     rigPosition(
                        "Hips",
                        {
                           x: riggedPose.Hips.position.x, // Reverse direction
                           y: riggedPose.Hips.position.y + 1, // Add a bit of height
                           z: -riggedPose.Hips.position.z, // Reverse direction
                        },
                        1,
                        0.07
                     );

                     rigRotation("Chest", riggedPose.Spine, 0.25, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("Spine", riggedPose.Spine, 0.45, 0.3);

                     rigRotation("RightUpperArm", riggedPose.RightUpperArm, 1, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("RightLowerArm", riggedPose.RightLowerArm, 1, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("LeftUpperArm", riggedPose.LeftUpperArm, 1, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("LeftLowerArm", riggedPose.LeftLowerArm, 1, 0.3);

                     rigRotation("LeftUpperLeg", riggedPose.LeftUpperLeg, 1, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("LeftLowerLeg", riggedPose.LeftLowerLeg, 1, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("RightUpperLeg", riggedPose.RightUpperLeg, 1, 0.3);
                     rigRotation("RightLowerLeg", riggedPose.RightLowerLeg, 1, 0.3);
                  }

                  // Animate Hands
                  if (leftHandLandmarks) {
                     riggedLeftHand = await Hand.solve(leftHandLandmarks, "Left");
                     rigRotation("LeftHand", {
                        // Combine pose rotation Z and hand rotation X Y
                        z: riggedPose.LeftHand.z,
                        y: riggedLeftHand.LeftWrist.y,
                        x: riggedLeftHand.LeftWrist.x,
                     });

                     rigRotation("LeftRingProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftRingProximal);
                     rigRotation("LeftRingIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftRingIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("LeftRingDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftRingDistal);
                     rigRotation("LeftIndexProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftIndexProximal);
                     rigRotation("LeftIndexIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftIndexIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("LeftIndexDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftIndexDistal);
                     rigRotation("LeftMiddleProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftMiddleProximal);
                     rigRotation("LeftMiddleIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftMiddleIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("LeftMiddleDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftMiddleDistal);
                     rigRotation("LeftThumbProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftThumbProximal);
                     rigRotation("LeftThumbIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftThumbIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("LeftThumbDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftThumbDistal);
                     rigRotation("LeftLittleProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftLittleProximal);
                     rigRotation("LeftLittleIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftLittleIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("LeftLittleDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftLittleDistal);
                  }
                  if (rightHandLandmarks) {
                     riggedRightHand = await Hand.solve(rightHandLandmarks, "Right");
                     rigRotation("RightHand", {
                        // Combine Z axis from pose hand and X/Y axis from hand wrist rotation
                        z: riggedPose.RightHand.z,
                        y: riggedRightHand.RightWrist.y,
                        x: riggedRightHand.RightWrist.x,
                     });
                     rigRotation("RightRingProximal", riggedRightHand.RightRingProximal);
                     rigRotation("RightRingIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightRingIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("RightRingDistal", riggedRightHand.RightRingDistal);
                     rigRotation("RightIndexProximal", riggedRightHand.RightIndexProximal);
                     rigRotation("RightIndexIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightIndexIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("RightIndexDistal", riggedRightHand.RightIndexDistal);
                     rigRotation("RightMiddleProximal", riggedRightHand.RightMiddleProximal);
                     rigRotation("RightMiddleIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightMiddleIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("RightMiddleDistal", riggedRightHand.RightMiddleDistal);
                     rigRotation("RightThumbProximal", riggedRightHand.RightThumbProximal);
                     rigRotation("RightThumbIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightThumbIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("RightThumbDistal", riggedRightHand.RightThumbDistal);
                     rigRotation("RightLittleProximal", riggedRightHand.RightLittleProximal);
                     rigRotation("RightLittleIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightLittleIntermediate);
                     rigRotation("RightLittleDistal", riggedRightHand.RightLittleDistal);
                  }
               };
               await animateVRM(JSON.parse(this.data.motion));

               const clock = new THREE.Clock();
               function animate() {
                  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                  const delta = clock.getDelta();
                  if (currentMixer) {
                     currentMixer.update(delta);
                  }
                  if (currentVrm) {
                     currentVrm.update(delta);
                  }
               }
               animate();
            }
         }
      }
   },
});*
```

Here is the related libraries I use

```
    "@mediapipe/camera_utils": "^0.3.1632432234",
    "@mediapipe/drawing_utils": "^0.3.1620248257",
    "@mediapipe/face_mesh": "^0.4.1633559619",
    "@mediapipe/holistic": "^0.5.1635989137",
"@pixiv/three-vrm": "1.0.0-beta.11",
        "@pixiv/types-vrm-0.0": "1.0.0-beta.11",
        "@pixiv/types-vrmc-vrm-1.0": "1.0.0-beta.11",
"@pixiv/three-vrm": "1.0.0-beta.11",
"aframe",
"three.js"
```

Answer (score 0):

The key fix is to change:

```js
const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getRawBoneNode(VRMHumanBoneName[name]);
```

to:

```js
const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getNormalizedBoneNode(VRMHumanBoneName[name]);
```

After this, body tracking works as expected: [Image of hand and arm tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9k3xB.png)

---

Here is the full code with unnecessary parts such as Mixamo and face rigging removed, and live motion tracking added. In the future, a minimum working example that can be immediately tested would be much easier to understand and work with.

index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <style>
        #video {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video id="video" width="1280px" height="720px"></video>
<a-scene>
    <a-entity m-avatar></a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```js
import "aframe";
import { VRMHumanBoneName, VRMLoaderPlugin, VRMUtils } from "@pixiv/three-vrm";
import { GLTFLoader } from "three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js";
import * as THREE from "three";
import { Holistic } from "@mediapipe/holistic";
import { Camera } from "@mediapipe/camera_utils";
import { Hand, Pose } from "kalidokit";

async function loadVRM() {
    return new Promise((resolve, _reject) => {
        // Import Character VRM
        const loader = new GLTFLoader();
        loader.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
        loader.register((parser) => new VRMLoaderPlugin(parser));

        // Import model from URL, add your own model here
        loader.load(
            "https://cdn.glitch.com/29e07830-2317-4b15-a044-135e73c7f840%2FAshtra.vrm?v=1630342336981",

            gltf => {
                VRMUtils.removeUnnecessaryJoints(gltf.scene);
                resolve(gltf.userData.vrm);
            },

            progress =>
                console.log(
                    "Loading model...",
                    100.0 * (progress.loaded / progress.total),
                    "%"
                ),

            error => console.error(error)
        );
    });
}

AFRAME.registerComponent("m-avatar", {
    schema: {
        src: { type: "string" },
        motion: { type: "string" },
    },
    async init() {
    },
    async update(oldData) {
        this.camera = AFRAME.scenes[0].camera;
        this.scene = this.el.object3D;
        this.renderer = AFRAME.scenes[0].renderer;
        var currentVrm = null;
        if (this.data.src !== oldData.src) {
            this.vrm = await loadVRM().then(async (vrm) => {
                currentVrm = vrm;
                this.scene.add(currentVrm.scene);
                const head = currentVrm.humanoid.getBoneNode("head");
                this.camera.position.set(0.0, head.getWorldPosition(new THREE.Vector3()).y, 6.0);
                return vrm;
            });
        }

        if (this.vrm) {
            // Animate Rotation Helper function
            const rigRotation = (name, rotation = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, dampener = 1, lerpAmount = 0.3) => {
                if (!this.vrm) {
                    return;
                }
                //const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getBoneNode(VRMSchema.HumanoidBoneName[name]); //
                const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getNormalizedBoneNode(VRMHumanBoneName[name]);

                if (!Part) {
                    return;
                }

                let euler = new THREE.Euler(rotation.x * dampener, rotation.y * dampener, rotation.z * dampener, rotation.rotationOrder || "XYZ");
                let quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion().setFromEuler(euler);
                Part.quaternion.slerp(quaternion, lerpAmount); // interpolate
            };

            // Animate Position Helper Function
            const rigPosition = (name, position = { x: 0, y: 0, z: 0 }, dampener = 1, lerpAmount = 0.3) => {
                if (!this.vrm) {
                    return;
                }
                //const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getBoneNode(VRMSchema.HumanoidBoneName[name]); //
                const Part = this.vrm.humanoid.getNormalizedBoneNode(VRMHumanBoneName[name]);

                if (!Part) {
                    return;
                }
                let vector = new THREE.Vector3(position.x * dampener, position.y * dampener, position.z * dampener);
                Part.position.lerp(vector, lerpAmount); // interpolate
            };

            currentVrm = this.vrm;
            if (currentVrm) {
                /* VRM Character Animator */
                const animateVRM = async (results) => {
                    // Take the results from `Holistic` and animate character based on its Face, Pose, and Hand Keypoints.
                    let riggedPose, riggedLeftHand, riggedRightHand, riggedFace;

                    const faceLandmarks = results.faceLandmarks;
                    // Pose 3D Landmarks are with respect to Hip distance in meters
                    const pose3DLandmarks = results.ea; //results.ea;
                    // Pose 2D landmarks are with respect to videoWidth and videoHeight
                    const pose2DLandmarks = results.poseLandmarks;
                    // Be careful, hand landmarks may be reversed
                    const leftHandLandmarks = results.rightHandLandmarks;
                    const rightHandLandmarks = results.leftHandLandmarks;

                    const videoElement = document.getElementById("video-in");

                    // Animate Pose
                    if (pose2DLandmarks && pose3DLandmarks) {
                        riggedPose = await Pose.solve(pose3DLandmarks, pose2DLandmarks, {
                            runtime: "mediapipe",
                            video: videoElement,
                        });

                        rigRotation("Hips", riggedPose.Hips.rotation, 0.7);

                        rigPosition(
                            "Hips",
                            {
                                x: riggedPose.Hips.position.x, // Reverse direction
                                y: riggedPose.Hips.position.y + 1, // Add a bit of height
                                z: -riggedPose.Hips.position.z, // Reverse direction
                            },
                            1,
                            0.07
                        );

                        rigRotation("Chest", riggedPose.Spine, 0.25, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("Spine", riggedPose.Spine, 0.45, 0.3);

                        rigRotation("RightUpperArm", riggedPose.RightUpperArm, 1, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("RightLowerArm", riggedPose.RightLowerArm, 1, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("LeftUpperArm", riggedPose.LeftUpperArm, 1, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("LeftLowerArm", riggedPose.LeftLowerArm, 1, 0.3);

                        rigRotation("LeftUpperLeg", riggedPose.LeftUpperLeg, 1, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("LeftLowerLeg", riggedPose.LeftLowerLeg, 1, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("RightUpperLeg", riggedPose.RightUpperLeg, 1, 0.3);
                        rigRotation("RightLowerLeg", riggedPose.RightLowerLeg, 1, 0.3);
                    }

                    // Animate Hands
                    if (leftHandLandmarks) {
                        riggedLeftHand = await Hand.solve(leftHandLandmarks, "Left");
                        rigRotation("LeftHand", {
                            // Combine pose rotation Z and hand rotation X Y
                            z: riggedPose.LeftHand.z,
                            y: riggedLeftHand.LeftWrist.y,
                            x: riggedLeftHand.LeftWrist.x,
                        });

                        rigRotation("LeftRingProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftRingProximal);
                        rigRotation("LeftRingIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftRingIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("LeftRingDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftRingDistal);
                        rigRotation("LeftIndexProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftIndexProximal);
                        rigRotation("LeftIndexIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftIndexIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("LeftIndexDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftIndexDistal);
                        rigRotation("LeftMiddleProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftMiddleProximal);
                        rigRotation("LeftMiddleIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftMiddleIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("LeftMiddleDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftMiddleDistal);
                        rigRotation("LeftThumbProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftThumbProximal);
                        rigRotation("LeftThumbIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftThumbIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("LeftThumbDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftThumbDistal);
                        rigRotation("LeftLittleProximal", riggedLeftHand.LeftLittleProximal);
                        rigRotation("LeftLittleIntermediate", riggedLeftHand.LeftLittleIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("LeftLittleDistal", riggedLeftHand.LeftLittleDistal);
                    }
                    if (rightHandLandmarks) {
                        riggedRightHand = await Hand.solve(rightHandLandmarks, "Right");
                        rigRotation("RightHand", {
                            // Combine Z axis from pose hand and X/Y axis from hand wrist rotation
                            z: riggedPose.RightHand.z,
                            y: riggedRightHand.RightWrist.y,
                            x: riggedRightHand.RightWrist.x,
                        });
                        rigRotation("RightRingProximal", riggedRightHand.RightRingProximal);
                        rigRotation("RightRingIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightRingIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("RightRingDistal", riggedRightHand.RightRingDistal);
                        rigRotation("RightIndexProximal", riggedRightHand.RightIndexProximal);
                        rigRotation("RightIndexIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightIndexIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("RightIndexDistal", riggedRightHand.RightIndexDistal);
                        rigRotation("RightMiddleProximal", riggedRightHand.RightMiddleProximal);
                        rigRotation("RightMiddleIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightMiddleIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("RightMiddleDistal", riggedRightHand.RightMiddleDistal);
                        rigRotation("RightThumbProximal", riggedRightHand.RightThumbProximal);
                        rigRotation("RightThumbIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightThumbIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("RightThumbDistal", riggedRightHand.RightThumbDistal);
                        rigRotation("RightLittleProximal", riggedRightHand.RightLittleProximal);
                        rigRotation("RightLittleIntermediate", riggedRightHand.RightLittleIntermediate);
                        rigRotation("RightLittleDistal", riggedRightHand.RightLittleDistal);
                    }
                };

                // Start animation loop.
                {
                    const clock = new THREE.Clock();

                    function animate() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
                        const delta = clock.getDelta();
                        if (currentVrm) {
                            currentVrm.update(delta);
                        }
                    }

                    animate();
                }

                {
                    // Start tracking.
                    const onResults = (results) => {
                        animateVRM(results);
                    }

                    // Start mediapipe.
                    const holistic = new Holistic({
                        locateFile: file => {
                            return `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mediapipe/holistic@0.5.1635989137/${file}`;
                        }
                    });

                    holistic.setOptions({
                        modelComplexity: 1,
                        smoothLandmarks: true,
                        minDetectionConfidence: 0.7,
                        minTrackingConfidence: 0.7,
                        refineFaceLandmarks: true,
                    });
                    holistic.onResults(onResults);

                    const videoElement = document.querySelector("#video");
                    await new Camera(videoElement, {
                        onFrame: async () => await holistic.send({ image: videoElement }),
                        width: 640,
                        height: 480
                    }).start();
                }
            }
        }
    },
});
```

`esbuild` was used to bundle `script.js` into `index.js`:

```
./node_modules/.bin/esbuild script.js --bundle --outfile=index.js
```

---

Here are the dependencies and dependency versions I used:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@mediapipe/camera_utils": "^0.3.1640029074",
    "@mediapipe/drawing_utils": "^0.3.1620248257",
    "@mediapipe/holistic": "0.5.1635989137",
    "@pixiv/three-vrm": "1.0.9",
    "@types/aframe": "^1.2.2",
    "aframe": "^1.4.1",
    "kalidokit": "^1.1.5",
    "three": "0.149.0"
  }
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer but changing it to getNormalizedBoneNode doesn't make any difference